# Super Linear Speedup - Python - Cluster - Multiple Processes

Tags: python, numpy

I parallelized a program which uses fairly large matrices. The program depicts the Ising model, from statistical mechanics. On my laptop everything works fine - even the visualization shows the behaviour I expect. Now I wanted to see how it scales using many CPUs, so I used a cluster computer I have at hand. Well, I get super linear speedup. First I thought it's not a big deal since it's possible that when I use multiple processes the problem size gets smaller and thus might fit into the cache. So no time consuming coping from cache to ram and back will slow it down. However, I even get super linear speedup for one CPU. I wouldn't expect that. If the whole system (matrix) doesn't fit into the cache for the sequential version then it also shouldn't fit into it using the parallel version with only one CPU, right?

I've done a check on my laptop. Averaged over 5 runs, the parallel version using one CPU is a tiny bit slower than the sequential version. I guess this is okay since there are some statements in the parallel version which I don't have in the sequential one.

Any ideas what this could be all about? Is the super linear speedup reasonable?

Note: I'm programming in python using numpy and for the parallel version, processes and shmarray.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "super linear"? Some stats could be helpful.

Comment: When parallelizing a program the ideal case is linear speedup. This means the factor by which a program should get faster is equal to the number of CPUs added (for example going from one CPU to two should make the program twice as fast (ideally)). Super linear means speedup larger than the number of CPUs added (e.g. going from one to two CPUs makes the program more than twice as fast). This can happen in some cases. That's what I meant in my original post with the cache thing.

Comment: As for stats: For four CPUs I get speedups up to 4.8. For two CPU up to 2.6 and for one CPU up to 1.22.

Comment: It looks to me like each CPU in the cluster computer is about 1.2-1.3 times as fast as the CPU in your laptop.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear here. The speed of the CPUs in the cluster doesn't matter per se. The speedups I get from the cluster are calculated purely with times I received from the cluster, i.e. I ran the sequential version on the cluster and the parallel version. Then I calculated the speedups using those times. On my laptop I only wanted to check whether the parallel version using one CPU is faster than the sequential one using one CPU.

Comment: @Robert if I correctly understand [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) it is not possible to archive superlinerization (you'll talking about how fast you're growing, right?) on the same processors.

Comment: Correct, super linear speedup isn't possible in general. The best you can hope for is linear speedup BUT there are cases where it is possible. Those are cases where, for example, the whole problem won't fit into the cache so the program has to do a lot of coping from cache to ram and back to perform all the calculations. Now if you break the problem into smaller ones then they might fit into the cache, so no time consuming coping has to be done, thus giving the program an extra 'boost'. This would be observed as super linear speedup.

Comment: Can't that be a result of hyperthreading for the 1 CPU case? Aren't there some considerable waits for I/O or similar?

Comment: Rather not. The CPU in my laptop is P8600. It doesn't have hyperthreading. As for I/O, the program is a simulation of the Ising model. It doesn't wait for any I/O.

Comment: How big are the arrays and how big are the caches?  What kind of algorithm are you using?  I did some HPC research in college and we definitely found programs that got super-linear speedup due to caching like you said.  More info for real answers.